# I will burn everything

Tags: riddle, knowledge, affix-riddle

I form especially close bonds with others.
Remove my infix, and my superior quality is apparent.
Remove my suffix, and you will become sick of me.
Add a Cl to many of me, and I will burn your house and the ground below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are

> FLUORINE.

I form especially close bonds with others.

> True. (Chemical bonds, of course.)

Remove my infix, and my superior quality is apparent.

> That's FINE.

Remove my suffix, and you will become sick of me.

> Time was, the contagious illness everyone worried about getting was the FLU.

Add a Cl to many of me, and I will burn your house and the ground below it.

> As the wise man saith, ["Sand won't save you this time"](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2008/02/26/sand_wont_save_you_this_time).

Comment: The last clue kinda gave it away didn't it?

Comment: It really did :-).